# How do electrons flow from the earth to body that has been connected to a wire?

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose a positively charged rod is brought to an uncharged object, the object has electrons accumulated to the side where the rod was brought (on one end) & protons on the other end. If we connect the side of the body where are protons are accumulated, to a wire and earth it, how do electrons flow from the ground to neutralize the protons ?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162444/207455

Comment: Solid conductors do not contain protons*, except bound in nuclei, and the nuclei are not mobile. The conductivity results from mobility of (part of) the valence electrons. What you are describing would apply to a hydrogen plasma.*Except the hypothetical high pressure form of hydrogen.

Comment: The electrons flow through the earthed wire.

Comment: @my2cts I'm talking about any arbitrary object that is a conductor.

Comment: Connected to Earth by a wire?

Comment: @my2cts as in earthed..

Answer (score -1):

Both electrons and protons experience force of attraction due to potential difference, but only electrons move as the are extremely light as compared to protons. For example, if you throw a ball upwards both ball and earth exert force on each other but only ball moves towards earth. Moreover, the protons are not free like electrons, not at least at room temperature. The protons are bound in nuclei by other short range nuclear force by neutrons. So it is the electron which has to move.